# How do i prevent behaviorsubject next() calls from overwriting each other?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I have a `BehaviorSubject` variable called `saveToLocalStorage` and in one method the `next()` method is called twice. This is causing a problem because only one of the two is ever completed. The other one is simply overwritten. The service that is `subscribed` to the calls saves the data to localstorage nothing else. Apparently there has to be a delay between both next calls so i decided to handle the calls inside an `Observable` like so (lets assume that the if statement returns `true`):

```
Observable.of(1).pipe(
  tap(()=> {if(this.currentWebAppMode !== newMode){
    this.saveToLocalStorage.next([DataType.STORED_RESULTS, null])}; 
  }),
  debounceTime(100))
  .subscribe(result => this.saveToLocalStorage.next([DataType.WEB_APP_MODE, newMode]));
```

This works, but feels really hacky. So i was wondering whether there is a more proper way to make sure both subsequent `next()` calls to `saveToLocalStorage` are able to execute properly.

Edit: Thanks to Deborah i was able to ameliorate my solution by incorporating the `concatMap` operator instead of `tab` and `debounceTime` Heres my new code:

```
Observable.of(1).pipe(
  concatMap(()=> {if(this.dataStoreService.currentAppMode !== newMode){
    this.saveToLocalStorage.next([DataType.STORED_RESULTS, null])};
  return of(true)}))
  .subscribe(result => this.saveToLocalStorage.next([DataType.WEB_APP_MODE, newMode]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `concatMap` will ensure that each source value is processed in a serial fashion.

The code below first creates an "action" stream that emits the values (I'm just emitting 1 and 2 but you get the idea).

As each item is emitted, the code executes the desired pipeline.

Within the pipeline, the code uses `concatMap` to ensure each emitted item is fully processed. If an item is emitted before the first item's processing is done, the second item is cached internally and will be processed as soon as the first emitted item's processing is complete.

In this example, the code calls `doSave` to actually perform the saving to local storage process ... which emits true if the save was successful.

Something like this:

```
  saveSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(1);
  saveAction$ = this.saveSubject.asObservable();

  source = this.saveAction$.pipe(
    concatMap(value =>
      this.doSave(value)
    )
  );

  ngOnInit() {
    this.source.subscribe();
    this.saveSubject.next(2);
  }

  doSave(value) {
    console.log('Emited value:', value);
    // Save to local storage
    return of(true);
  }
```

I have a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-concatmap-deborahk

Comment: Thank you Deborah, I made a new solution based on your code, i've also included it in my question post. I do have one question though. In your example you are ending `saveAction` with `$`. What does this signify? Does it mean that `saveAction$` is holding an `Observable` ?

Comment: Yes. Common naming conventions suggests that any variable that is an Observable should be suffixed with a `$`.

Comment: Something else that may be of interest: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck

Comment: The `$` notation was attributed to Andre Staltz by Ben Lesh, you can read a short writeup here about it: https://medium.com/@benlesh/observables-and-finnish-notation-df8356ed1c9b